# Microsoft SQL Server Agent Job: Get Schedule that triggered the Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I have SQL Server Agent Job on my System that copies data into at table for later evaluation purposes. The Job runs on two types of schedules every Friday every week and last day of the month. The target data records should also contain a column indicating the schedule that originally triggered the job. But I found no way so far to receive this data as parameter or so. I'm using a Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

I did a web search but maybe searched for the wrong keywords. I also thought about comparing current time to expected runtime per schedule but that seemed to be not a fault tolerant option to me.

I like to fill a column "schedule" with values like "End of week", "End of month"

Comment: Is it the schedule that matters? Or just "is it the last day of the month or not?". If the latter, build that logic into your query and leave the vagaries of scheduling to the Agent.

Comment: It's the schedule that matters. Some of the evaluations of the customers only target the end of week schedule.

Comment: Interesting. I'd think it's the business rule (i.e. "some things happen during non-month end" and "other things happen at month end") and not the technical implementation (i.e. "the SQL Agent job was started for this reason"). But it's your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search and analyzing I finally found a solution that at least fit my needs:
The undocumented and unsupport stored procedures provides the schedule that triggered a job ind Column Request Source ID:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, garbage
```

[image]

see also: https://am2.co/2016/02/xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs_alt/

Answer (score 1):

sys tables are your friend here. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

- sysjobs has your job information.
- sysjobschedules links your job to its schedule.
- sysschedules has your schedule info.

  ```
  SELECT j.*
       , s.*
    FROM sysjobs j
    JOIN sysjobschedules js ON j.id = js.job_id
    JOIN sysschedules     s ON js.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
   WHERE j.name = 'your job name here'
  ```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that won't help me finding the schedule that acually triggered the job (if there is more than one). In that case 'your job name here' would return all schedules and won't help me...

Comment: If you put your job name in the query, it would return only schedules that can fire that job. You say there are two (one for Fridays, one for monthly). If there is more than one, you will see two rows in sysjobschedules with different schedule_id values. Also, you can then dig through sysjobhistory to find out when it ran and then check schedule run times to find out which schedule ran it.